# How to add encoders/codec to opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, codec, video-encoding

So I am trying to use opencv `VideoWriter` but the thing is it only has about 5 codec options and does not have the codecs I would like to use such as HFYU  (which support an alpha channel).

I want to know what exactly I need to do to get opencv to be able to use more codecs.

The codecs I can currently see (when passing -1 to videowriter) are:

- Intel IYUV codec
- Intel IYUV codec
- Microsoft RLE
- Microsoft Video 1
- Lagarith Lossless Codec
- Full Frames (Uncompressed)

Thanks in advance.